# Tensorflow : Multi labels classification prediction is same for every test data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to work with Multi label classification problem , [Dataset is Available here](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/dataset_smja.php?cod=925)

So I tranformed my input for LSTM RNN as :

Raw data was :

```
[-0.106902 -0.111342  0.104265  0.114448  0.067026  0.040118  0.018003
 -0.082054 -0.092087 -0.192697 -0.026802  0.215549  0.344768  0.324198
  0.200254  0.234357 -0.040812  0.025356 -0.193163 -0.019159 -0.051112
  0.070979  0.020293  0.075366  0.126615  0.091983  0.138466  0.23322
  0.024106  0.069623  0.043408  0.107059 -0.072603  0.022784  0.063041
  0.089568 -0.088068 -0.10704  -0.061862 -0.008561  0.036751 -0.052483
 -0.171235 -0.135565  0.045164 -0.12917  -0.115914 -0.105413  0.005252
 -0.06102  -0.057999 -0.064665 -0.072545  0.021969 -0.045153  0.019881
  0.022636 -0.007741  0.076754 -0.03363  -0.000429  0.115502  0.139804
  0.102889 -0.158891 -0.094767  0.046051  0.147124  0.078688 -0.063363
 -0.024232  0.050911  0.018356 -0.016907 -0.017603 -0.037143 -0.021808
 -0.148908 -0.001696  0.003607 -0.028734 -0.074155 -0.07131  -0.033052
  0.051065  0.085901  0.037884  0.076677 -0.004175  0.024224  0.00108
 -0.03285  -0.067774 -0.021328 -0.038708 -0.02537  -0.053335  0.015339
 -0.014152  0.024729 -0.052682 -0.016872  0.090514]
```

I converted to 3 dim for RNN LSTM like this:

```
   [[[-0.072794], [0.181316], [0.014368], [0.028411], [-0.041242], [-0.004056], [-0.064594], 
     [0.003051], [0.055096], [-0.114891], [0.067934], [0.037837], [0.025255], [0.050971], 
     [0.075224], [0.018362], [-0.104191], [-0.110567], [-0.027323], [0.059402], [0.081574], 
     [-0.023793], [-0.064557], [-0.027703], [-0.025198], [-0.016347], [0.029568], [-0.061661], 
     [-0.092653], [-0.186273], [-0.041202], [0.038554], [-0.059853], [0.123145], [-0.096088], 
     [-0.282818], [-0.125915], [0.204784], [-0.178102], [0.173425], [-0.10509], [-0.223132], 
     [-0.115442], [0.028586], [-0.102809], [-0.168281], [-0.029156], [-0.16269], [0.205518], 
     [0.058809], [-0.036977], [-0.00827], [0.037344], [0.086508], [-0.070408], [-0.106666], 
     [0.067168], [0.009743], [-0.006985], [0.116635], [0.087596], [0.066868], [0.096816], 
     [0.116658], [0.00165], [-0.079719], [0.015966], [0.057896], [-0.092253], [-0.009542], 
     [0.005439], [0.162932], [-0.206875], [0.119895], [0.007899], [-9.6e-05], [-0.253397], 
     [0.0976], [0.131022], [0.07027], [-0.057863], [-0.075103], [-0.021241], [-0.057738], 
     [-0.046753], [0.096566], [-0.0508], [0.122675], [-0.062557], [0.030779], [-0.034159], 
     [-0.05235], [-0.06705], [0.165413], [-0.05623], [0.181517], [-0.056385], [-0.002522], 
     [-0.049523], [-0.067518], [-0.062527], [-0.027574], [0.075115]]]
```

And labels are :

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Now my model is : ( It's a simple rnn lstm model )

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import numpy as np
import data_preprocessing





batch=100
iteration=int(2175//100)  #total dataset//batch_size
epoch=20

class RNNLSTM():

    def __init__(self):

        tf.reset_default_graph()

        input_x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name='input',shape=[None,103,1])  #batch_size x seq_lenth x dim

        labels_o = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name='labels',shape=[None,14])     #batch_size x labels

        self.placeholder={'input':input_x,'output':labels_o}

        with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:

            cell=rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=100)

            dropout_wrapper=rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell,output_keep_prob=0.5)

            model,(fs,fw)=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(dropout_wrapper,dtype=tf.float32,inputs=input_x)

        batch_major = tf.transpose(model,[1,0,2])

        weights=tf.get_variable(name='weights',shape=[100,14],initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01),dtype=tf.float32)

        bias   = tf.get_variable(name='bias',shape=[14],initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01),dtype=tf.float32)

        #logits
        logits= tf.matmul(batch_major[-1],weights) + bias

        #passing the logits to sigmoid for normalization
        pred=tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(logits))

        #accuracy calculation
        accuracy = tf.equal(pred,labels_o)

        #cross entropy
        ce=tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=labels_o)

        #calculating the loss
        loss=tf.reduce_mean(ce)

        #claculating accuracy
        accuracy1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(accuracy, tf.float32))

        #training default learning rate is 0.001
        train=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

        self.out={'accuracy':accuracy1,'pred':accuracy,'prob':pred,'loss':loss,'train':train,'logits':logits}

        self.test={'pred':pred}



def execute_model(model):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for i in range(epoch):
            for j in range(iteration):

                datain=data_preprocessing.get_train_data()['input']
                labels=data_preprocessing.get_train_data()['labels']
                fina_out=sess.run(model.out,feed_dict={model.placeholder['input']:datain,model.placeholder['output']:labels})

                print('epoch', i, 'iteration', j, 'loss', fina_out['loss'],'accuracy', fina_out['accuracy'])


        print("Now testing the model with test data..")

        for i in range(30):
            data_test = data_preprocessing.get_test_data()['input']
            labels = data_preprocessing.get_test_data()['labels']

            outputp = sess.run(model.test,
                               feed_dict={model.placeholder['input']: data_test})

            print(outputp['pred'], 'vs', labels)



if '__main__'==__name__:

    result=RNNLSTM()
    execute_model(result)
```

Even after 20 epoch the model is giving same result for test data , I tried to find on web and someone suggested to increase your batch size if result is same , I did from 50 to 100 batch size but the result is still same , I think i am doing mistake somewhere maybe in loss calculation or anywhere , Please point out the mistake ,

output

```
epoch 0 iteration 0 loss 0.6922738 accuracy 0.595
epoch 0 iteration 1 loss 0.69211155 accuracy 0.57928574
epoch 0 iteration 2 loss 0.6916339 accuracy 0.61071426
epoch 0 iteration 3 loss 0.6909899 accuracy 0.73
epoch 0 iteration 4 loss 0.69043064 accuracy 0.7171429
....
....
....

epoch 19 iteration 15 loss 0.4839307 accuracy 0.77428573
epoch 19 iteration 16 loss 0.49799272 accuracy 0.76857144
epoch 19 iteration 17 loss 0.49267265 accuracy 0.7714286
epoch 19 iteration 18 loss 0.5134562 accuracy 0.7614286
epoch 19 iteration 19 loss 0.5096274 accuracy 0.76857144
epoch 19 iteration 20 loss 0.48447722 accuracy 0.77
```

prediction:

```
Predicted output                              vs      real output 
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]] vs [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: @openmark no effect :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole network above consists of just `1 LSTM cell` (and a dense layer).

In the `bi-directional LSTM` you have defined, you share the same LSTM cell for both directions. You need to define forward direction LSTM and backward direction LSTM and they should NOT be sharing weights.

You can check the graph variables and figure out whether the network has been created properly. Use:

```
 for v in tf.global_variables():
    print(v.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. The RNN or LSTM outputs are the same for different input during training.

My solution is:

Change the activation function in the RNN or LSTM cell to ReLU or others, rather than the default tanh.